# Can't access website with Apache ServerName error in Docker Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose, apache2

I've been following this [tutorial](https://blog.ssdnodes.com/blog/host-multiple-ssl-websites-docker-nginx/) to deploy several applications instead of the only one that I had previously with Docker in my VPS.

I've modified my apps `docker-compose.yml` files adding the variables like `VIRTUAL_HOST` and so on that were asked in the tutorial.

Every steps seems to go fine, but when I try to access my website through my domain, I can't. I receive a `503` error or not even a response.

The thing is that if I go to my `wordpress` container and check the log, I find:

> AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.18.0.6. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message

After it there're some more messages, but I don't know if any of them mean that the problem is solved:

> [Sat May 04 11:34:23.381791 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1] AH00163: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) PHP/7.2.17 configured -- resuming normal operations
>
> [Sat May 04 11:34:23.382141 2019] [core:notice] [pid 1] AH00094: Command line: 'apache2 -D FOREGROUND'

I would say that this is available to configure within the `Wordpress dashboard`, but since I can't access it, I can't fix it. Also I must say that **I'm not sure** if this is the problem that doesn't allow me to access any of the websites.

Any ideas about how to solve it?

### Data

Wordpress `docker-compose.yml` (the other one is similar, but with other folders, another domain, and so on):

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  db_mysql_btcsources:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - /root/wp_btcsources/database:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: xxx
      MYSQL_DATABASE: xxx
      MYSQL_USER: xxx
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: xxx
    container_name: mysql_btcsources

  wp_blog_btcsources:
    depends_on:
      - db_mysql_btcsources
    image: wordpress:latest
    expose:
      - 80
      - 443
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db_mysql_btcsources:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: xxx
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: xxx
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: xxx
      VIRTUAL_HOST: www.btcsources.es
      LETSENCRYPT_HOST: www.btcsources.es
      LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL: mypersonalmail@gmail.com
    volumes:
    - ./uploads.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini
    container_name: wp_btcsources

volumes:
  uploads.ini:

networks:
    default:
        external:
            name: nginx-proxy
```

Network `nginx-proxy` elements:

```
    "Containers": {
        "04335b2e1208a14bf5999eb10918017fb0e80fcf27b88b0eb427db621b01127e": {
            "Name": "nginx-proxy-le",
            "EndpointID": "ebf45a130674ec8174ea573706b57bc2fdde76c68365accc1e873cf3315ec8f9",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:04",
            "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.4/16",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "0b2f66f7d68fbc3c45994bdfcbca241419e2472e44de3b67eb2bc0e62513d404": {
            "Name": "wp_rociocorbart",
            "EndpointID": "7d24c5eda09e7388831bb6bfe39fd97d779e151fd54f97d777e10a6fea622484",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:08",
            "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.8/16",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "251e8f9929b8756f9a1aac29a640f80a74dd07a99f3ae25ff1314f3d7617c642": {
            "Name": "mysql_btcsources",
            "EndpointID": "b1f44a89dac9199ccfb59d8299ad97dda4a199d310016c2c97131260df76cfc9",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:05",
            "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.5/16",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "43bf6754b052eb5ff42b1dbb4537f407a0740673d8eeec438f06d7295deb7578": {
            "Name": "mysql_rociocorbart",
            "EndpointID": "c6a99711e81f8191376a26b0108179bc3278d1e962e6f6531ef60469e551dad9",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:07",
            "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.7/16",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "61153ca057c5940584e2ccf039883a730ecc4ff7169b44195eac585e73fb8f04": {
            "Name": "nginx-proxy-gen",
            "EndpointID": "21846fb74284682e0d6a9533f3742d1b91ced2958c085f6d456e644d8261b1ca",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:03",
            "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.3/16",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "c2364adf3405b1119773f26f6a02a65d834a521510d3a22ff54e88a53cfd293e": {
            "Name": "wp_btcsources",
            "EndpointID": "636bba853188b76ed46fae2aee88c89fd17d219d675d71c5dfd14d46a60efb22",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:06",
            "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.6/16",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "eb16ca01f3da71359c6fa1d2fd6d591ccca773e3c4f72d1a9b1e5da5245ad306": {
            "Name": "nginx-proxy",
            "EndpointID": "2bf727ac0a7689c5b2ffdda2a06275f05f6da81bc5d1dd12891126902850507e",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:02",
            "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.2/16",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        }
```

Nginx `config file` following the tutorial is [this one](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy/master/nginx.tmpl).

Nginx **logs**:

```
www.btcsources.es my_personal_ip_censored - - [04/May/2019:12:56:51 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 503 213 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0"
www.btcsources.es my_personal_ip_censored - - [04/May/2019:12:56:51 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 503 213 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0"
www.btcsources.es my_personal_ip_censored - - [04/May/2019:13:03:48 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 503 213 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0"
www.btcsources.es my_personal_ip_censored - - [04/May/2019:13:03:48 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 503 213 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0"
```

Nginx `docker-compose.yml` [modified](https://blog.ssdnodes.com/blog/host-multiple-ssl-websites-docker-nginx/) for **[debug](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx) mode**:

```
command: [nginx-debug, '-g', 'daemon off;']
```

Nginx **logs after executing it are the same**, so here it's the `compose up` output (note that these are the two containers of nginx that are not the proxy):

> Attaching to nginx-proxy, nginx-proxy-gen, nginx-proxy-le
> nginx-proxy-gen | 2019/05/04 15:16:24 Contents of
> /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf did not change. Skipping notification
> ''
>
> nginx-proxy-gen | 2019/05/04 15:16:24 Watching docker events
>
> nginx-proxy-gen | 2019/05/04 15:16:25 Contents of
> /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf did not change. Skipping notification
> ''
>
> nginx-proxy-gen | 2019/05/04 15:16:25 Received event start for
> container 2c49cd8d8e70
>
> nginx-proxy-le | Info: Custom Diffie-Hellman group found, generation
> skipped.
>
> nginx-proxy-le | Reloading nginx docker-gen (using separate container
> nginx-proxy-gen)...
>
> nginx-proxy-gen | 2019/05/04 15:16:25 Received signal: hangup
>
> nginx-proxy-gen | 2019/05/04 15:16:25 Received signal: hangup
>
> nginx-proxy-le | Reloading nginx (using separate container
> 13025827c7d261016e17d1cf6965ad511c145accbd80e27bd25b302f81239f13)...
>
> nginx-proxy-gen | 2019/05/04 15:16:25 Contents of
> /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf did not change. Skipping notification
> ''
>
> nginx-proxy-le | 2019/05/04 15:16:26 Generated
> '/app/letsencrypt_service_data' from 7 containers
>
> nginx-proxy-le | 2019/05/04 15:16:26 Running '/app/signal_le_service'
>
> nginx-proxy-le | 2019/05/04 15:16:26 Watching docker events
>
> nginx-proxy-le | 2019/05/04 15:16:26 Contents of
> /app/letsencrypt_service_data did not change. Skipping notification
> '/app/signal_le_service'
>
> nginx-proxy-le | /etc/nginx/certs/btcsources.es /app
>
> nginx-proxy-le | Reloading nginx docker-gen (using separate container
> nginx-proxy-gen)...
>
> nginx-proxy-gen | 2019/05/04 15:16:26 Received signal: hangup
>
> nginx-proxy-gen | 2019/05/04 15:16:26 Received signal: hangup
>
> nginx-proxy-le | Reloading nginx (using separate container
> 13025827c7d261016e17d1cf6965ad511c145accbd80e27bd25b302f81239f13)...
>
> nginx-proxy-le | Creating/renewal btcsources.es certificates...
> (btcsources.es)
>
> nginx-proxy-gen | 2019/05/04 15:16:26 Contents of
> /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf did not change. Skipping notification
> ''
>
> nginx-proxy-le | 2019-05-04 15:16:26,833:INFO:simp_le:1564:
> Certificates already exist and renewal is not necessary, exiting with
> status code 1.
>
> nginx-proxy-le | /app
>
> nginx-proxy-le | /etc/nginx/certs/rociocorbart.es /app
>
> nginx-proxy-le | Creating/renewal rociocorbart.es certificates...
> (rociocorbart.es)
>
> nginx-proxy-le | 2019-05-04 15:16:27,456:INFO:simp_le:1564:
> Certificates already exist and renewal is not necessary, exiting with
> status code 1.
>
> nginx-proxy-le | /app
>
> nginx-proxy-le | Sleep for 3600s
>
> nginx-proxy-gen | 2019/05/04 15:16:30 Debounce minTimer fired
>
> nginx-proxy-gen | 2019/05/04 15:16:30 Contents of
> /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf did not change. Skipping notification
> ''

Comment: Is your nginx reverse proxy also running in the `nginx-proxy` network? Could you add the relevant proxy pass rules of your nginx config to the question?

Comment: @bellackn added the containers of the network to the post. They're all inside it. The tutorial uses a configuration file for nginx that uses three containers to work with `let's encrypt`. Its configuration files following the tutorial are these ones: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy/master/nginx.tmpl

Comment: Please show what the logs of the `nginx-proxy` container look like when you try to access the Wordpress instance.

Comment: Deleted my previous comment, I didn't see the `503`. :) Could you enable verbose logging for nginx? [This](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/monitoring/debugging/) seems like a good guide for doing this. Probably you'll have to change the container's entrypoint for that.

Comment: @bellackn updated trying to use debug mode. I feel like making a mess with this last step.

Comment: Hm, this doesn't seem to be related. I feel like it's a bit over my head, so let's just hope for someone more experienced jumping in here... Still, what I would recommend here is building a _very_ basic, reproducible example, so people can try it out by theirselves more easily. Chances are that you find the problem by yourself by doing that, at least that's what happens to me regularly. :)

Answer (score 0):

I got the 503 error when I set the VIRTUAL_HOST as xxx.com (without www) but using www.xxx.com to visit my website.
It is supposed to work to visit your site via https://www.btcsources.es. Otherwise, it may arise the 503 error.
If so, this link maybe is a reference: https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy/issues/444